# AngularJS ng-click and callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous

On my web application, there are two kinds of users: guests & logged. The main page loads the same content for each.

My goal :

- When a registered user clicks the link, 2 ajax requests ($http) retrieve
  the data of another page and load them in a model.
- If the user is a guest, another model appears saying that he has to register.

My link :

```
<h4 ng-click="guestAction($event, showOne($event,card.id));">click me</h4>
```

GuestAction :

```
$scope.guestAction = function($event, callbackB) {

    $http.get('/guest/is-guest/').success(function(data) {
        console.log("isGuest retrieved : " + data);
        if (data == 1)
        {
            alert('guest spotted !');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('user');
            console.log(callbackB);
            eval('$scope.'+callbackB);
        }

    });

}
```

This way, if a guest is spotted, we return false and stop the execution. If it's a regular user, we execute the function showOne. As I want to do 2 asynchronous requests one after the other, I chose to use the callback trick.

The problem is that `showOne()` is executed directly when ng-click is launched. I tried to pass `showOne()` as a string, and `eval()` the string in `GuestAction`, but the parameters become undefined...

Any idea how to solve this problem? I want to use a generic method which fires a function only if the user is logged.

Comment: showOne is executing because you are invoking it in the html. You need to pass it as showOne (without () ). Also don't use 'eval' in angularjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using a service and promises, [see this AngularJS $q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

*You don't have to use a service for $http requests but that is just my preference, it makes your controller a lot cleaner*

Here is the service with the promise:

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http, $q) {

    var service = {};

    service.guestAction = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/guest/is-guest/').success(function(data) {
            console.log("isGuest retrieved : " + data);
            if (data == 1) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(false);
            }
        }).error(function (data) {
            deferred.reject('Error checking server.');
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return service;
});
```

And then in our controller we would call it something like so:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {

    $scope.guestAction = function($event, card) {
        myService.guestAction().then(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert('guest spotted !');
            } else {
                alert('user');
                // Then run your showOne
                // If this is also async I would use another promise
                $scope.showOne($event, card.id);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.error('ERROR: ' + error);
        })
    };
});
```

Now obviously you may have to change things here and there to get it working for your needs but what promises do is allow you to execute code and once the promise is returned then continue, I believe something like this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass functions as parameters without the parenthesis and pass in the parameters separately:

```
<h4 ng-click="guestAction($event,card.id, showOne);">click me</h4>
```

and

```
$scope.guestAction = function($event,id, callbackB) {

    $http.get('/guest/is-guest/').success(function(data) {
        console.log("isGuest retrieved : " + data);
        if (data == 1)
        {
            alert('guest spotted !');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('user');
            callbackB($event,id);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem. :)
The only drawback is that I have to pass the variables in guestAction, which makes it less generic. But it will be ok for what I want to do.